# Variable as title in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

**In short**: how can I print a html-header inside a chunk in rmarkdown (use a variable to create a header inside a code-chunk)?

**In long**:

Let's say I have a number of variables in my dataset (names also stored in the vector 'Vars'), and each group of 3 variables belongs to the same subject.

I can make a loop to plot all the variables, but I want the subject in a title. Something like:

#### Subject 1

Plot Var1

Plot Var2

Plot Var3

#### Subject 2

Plot Var 4

Plot Var 5

...

Following pseudo-code hopefully explains what I want to do:

````
```{r}

for (i in Vars)

    if(i%%3 == 1){
        print(## Subject[ceiling(i/3)])}

    plot(i)


```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Don't use print, it will add decorative stuff.
- Note the required double "\n"; check what happens with one only, so you are prepared when you forget it next time

````
```{r, results="asis", echo = FALSE}
i = 1
cat("## Subject", i, "\n")
plot(i)
i = 2
cat("\n\n## Subject", i, "\n")
plot(i)
```
````