# Rmarkdown: Word Document with Variable in Title

Tags: r, r-markdown

Something similar was asked a few years ago, but I do not think that it exactly fits my case.

[Variable as title in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892121/variable-as-title-in-rmarkdown)

Look at the snippet below. I would like the variable x to appear in the title of my word document. In reality x is the result of some computations (data is read and modified, but I believe this is not fundamental at this stage).

````
  ---
  title: "Country Focus in the Year x."
  output: word_document
  ---


 ```{r seq, echo=FALSE, eval=T}
  x<-2020
  ```
````

It must be trivial, but I am banging my head against the wall.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I think [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/dynamic-yaml.html) does what you want.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks